# Problems with WallTile in JAVA

Tags: java, game-engine, tile

I'm trying to create a Game Engine in java, as a way of learning in a course I'm attending, and now I'm learning how to program collisions between the player and a wall. But there's one problem I haven't seen anyone having, that basically my character runs into a wall and he just stops responding. And the way I say it, it's not like the program stopped responding, it's more like leaning against a wall the controls stop working, because even though everything seems to be stopped, the FPS keeps counting.
Here are screenshots of the parts I think are most important to show for this specific issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fcSr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COXzD.png)

Here's the file and codes on github for a deeper look:

https://github.com/TheAwesomeCake/Game-Engine.git

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, Java !== JavaScript

Comment: Did you take the [tour]? (You get a bronze badge after you do.)